# What's default password in docker container mysql-server when you don't set one?

Tags: mysql, docker

I am try to run a mysql container and connect with mysql client then:

I've used following commands:

```
docker run --name=mysql -d mysql/mysql-server:latest
docker exec -it mysql mysql -uroot -p
```

According to [tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-docker-container), the last command allow me configure database password but When I introduce the first password it fails...

[image]

The first password was root and I get an unusual error, then I try with admin, admin an even my linux user password but They don't work...

I would like to know what's the error?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are couple of ways to see the password.
**First Approach - Don't Run container in daemon mode**

Check the below command

```
docker run --name=mysql mysql/mysql-server:latest
```

and this will print the password in the terminal as look at the below logs

```
2020-05-28T23:41:01.418347Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock'
2020-05-28T23:41:01.666070Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-05-28T23:41:01.714420Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community 
Server - GPL.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
[Entrypoint] GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: PopiKQIjAS#OGj3x]yJOBLEn80p
[Entrypoint] ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
2020-05-28T23:41:06.208480Z 10 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.20).
2020-05-28T23:41:07.861667Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[Entrypoint] Server shut down
[Entrypoint] Setting root user as expired. Password will need to be changed before database can be used.
[Entrypoint] MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.20-1.1.16
2020-05-28T23:41:08.534785Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-05-28T23:41:08.549216Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-05-28T23:41:09.135591Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-05-28T23:41:09.369412Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-05-28T23:41:09.448584Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-05-28T23:41:09.500464Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Communi
ty Server - GPL.
```

**Second Approach - Run container in daemon mode & fetch the password from logs**
Check the below command to run the container

```
docker run -d --name=mysql mysql/mysql-server:latest
```

and then run the below command to fetch the password

```sh
docker logs mysql 2>&1 | grep GENERATED
```

Output of above command is:

```sh
[Entrypoint] GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: PopiKQIjAS#OGj3x]yJOBLEn80p
```

Once you have the password by one of the above-mentioned methods, you can then login with the below command using that password

```sh
docker exec -it mysql mysql -uroot -p
```

When asked, enter the generated root password (see the instructions above on how to find it). Because the `MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD` option is true by default, after you have connected a mysql client to the server, you must reset the server root password by issuing this statement:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Substitute `password` with the password of your choice. Once the password is reset, the server is ready for use.

> Ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/

Comment: I've noted that in Docker Hub there are two images: mysql and mysql/mysql-server. I tried to connect to mysql/mysql-server image as if it were a mysql  image. It was the origin of solution. I've noted mysql image run container with root user by defauly. I would like to know if mysql-server image run a mysql container where any user can connect. Thanks,

Answer (score 45):

`docker inspect <container_name_here>` command output shows root password among other params

Comment: It has resolved my issue :). When I have given $ in the password, the string after $ is ignored.

Comment: nice command, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

When starting a `mysql` [container](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) for the first time, there is no default password. The password you set while running the container is the default password that will be assigned to your `root`.

> Starting a MySQL instance is simple:
> $ ***docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag***

> where **some-mysql** is the name you want to assign to your container, ***my-secret-pw is the password to be set for the MySQL root user*** and tag is the tag specifying the MySQL version you want. See the list above for relevant tags.

Answer (score 4):

Following the documentation in: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/docker-mysql-getting-started.html

You get the password with command:

```
docker logs mysql 2>&1 | grep GENERATED
```

Example output:

```
GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: Axegh3kAJyDLaRuBemecis&EShOs
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no default password, try login in using:

```
sudo docker exec -it mysql mysql -u root
```

Comment: I get this error `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-u\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
`

Comment: Sorry i forget to add the service name.

Comment: Its not really your question but i think you be easier to just run docker passing the password: docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag

Comment: with the new command I get this: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).` I will also try set the password when run the mysql server but the tutorial suggested another method...

Comment: If you set the password you then need to pass -p when you run the command, like this: sudo docker exec -it mysql mysql -u root -p

Comment: You got confused with mysql and mysql-server, which are different images that have different behaviour